# To put it into a function JS

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

There is a condition, but it is cumbersome, how can you reduce this? Or write a function to which there would be an appeal.

```js
if (obj.Language.code == "ru") {
        if (obj.Tariff.typeCalc != 1) {
            if (obj.Price.Discount) {
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceWithDiscount', [Round(obj.Price.Itog), final_currency]);
            }
            else {
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceNoDiscount', [Round(obj.Price.Itog), final_currency]);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (obj.Price.Discount) {
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceWithDiscount', [Round(obj.Price.Itog), obj.Currency.symbol]);
            }
            else {
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceNoDiscount', [Round(obj.Price.Itog), obj.Currency.symbol]);
            }
        }
```

design

```js
if (obj.Language.code == "ru") {
}
else {
}
```

will meet often, do not want to pile up

```js
if (obj.Language.code == "ru") {
            if (obj.Price.Discount) {
                
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceWithDicountOutCity', [obj.Price.Itog, final_currency, Round(obj.Len.value, final_currency), nextkmprice]);
            }
            else {
                
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceOutCity', [obj.Price.Itog, final_currency, Round(obj.Len.value, final_currency), nextkmprice]);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (obj.Price.Discount) {
                
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceWithDicountOutCity', [obj.Price.Itog, obj.Currency.symbol, Round(obj.Len.value, obj.Currency.symbol), nextkmprice]);
            }
            else {
                
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceOutCity', [obj.Price.Itog, obj.Currency.symbol, Round(obj.Len.value, obj.Currency.symbol), nextkmprice]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to shorten this.

Comment: why `if (obj.Tariff.typeCalc != 1)` twice?

Comment: Could use language code as key to and object of functions and then reducing the inner functions to it's own function?

Comment: @NinaScholz Aha! My mistake.

Comment: @PatrickSturm there is a condition such that if a language code RU then the condition is, if not more.

Comment: @PatrickSturm I'd like to see your option, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a single outer check and two conditionals.

```
if (obj.Tariff.typeCalc != 1) {
    t += getText(
        obj.Language.code,
        obj.Price.Discount ? 'PriceWithDiscount' : 'PriceNoDiscount',
        [
            Round(obj.Price.Itog),
            obj.Language.code == "ru" ? final_currency : obj.Currency.symbol
        ]
    );
}
```

For the last problem, you could store `currency` in advance and use the variable instead of multiple condition statements.

```
var currency = obj.Language.code == "ru" ? final_currency : obj.Currency.symbol;

t += getText(
    obj.Language.code,
    obj.Price.Discount ? 'PriceWithDicountOutCity' : 'PriceOutCity',
    [
        obj.Price.Itog,
        currency,
        Round(obj.Len.value, currency),
        nextkmprice
    ]
);
```

Comment: cool! and if there were more parameters how to build? example                                 t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceWithDicountOutCity', [obj.Price.Itog, obj.Currency.symbol, Round(obj.Len.value, obj.Currency.symbol), nextkmprice]);
        }
        else {
            t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceOutCity', [obj.Price.Itog, obj.Currency.symbol, Round(obj.Len.value, obj.Currency.symbol), nextkmprice]);    instead "obj.Currency.symbol"  substitute "final_currency" and "Round(obj.Len.value, obj.Currency.symbol)" "Round(obj.Len.value, final_currency)"

Comment: you could add a variable (if i understand the question correctly), like `var symbol =  obj.Language.code == "ru" ? final_currency : obj.Currency.symbol
;` and take the variable instead of the conditional statement/s.

Comment: for example, with several variables I can't make the code easier as you did                obj.Price.Itog, obj.Language.code == "ru", nextkmprice ? final_currency, Round(obj.Len.value, final_currency) : obj.Currency.symbol, Round(obj.Len.value, obj.Currency.symbol)         but that's not right, is it?

Comment: i am afraid, the last makes no sense to me. mabe you edit the question and add the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the ternary operator to set values based on conditions. Then you can get rid of some of the redundant code. You can simplify it to something like this:

```
        if (obj.Tariff.typeCalc != 1) {
            var priceType = obj.Price.Discount ? 'PriceWithDiscount' : 'PriceNoDiscount';
            var currencyType = obj.Language.code == "ru" ? final_currency : obj.Currency.symbol;
            t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, priceType, [Round(obj.Price.Itog), currencyType]);
        }
```

ES6 using let:

```
        if (obj.Tariff.typeCalc != 1) {
            let priceType = obj.Price.Discount ? 'PriceWithDiscount' : 'PriceNoDiscount';
            let currencyType = obj.Language.code == "ru" ? final_currency : obj.Currency.symbol;
            t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, priceType, [Round(obj.Price.Itog), currencyType]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible use of an object with language based function keys:

```
function langObj(opts){
    this.tarrif = opts.tarrifType;
    this.symbols = [{
        "au":"$",
        "us":"$"
        // include more
    }];

    this.doStuff = function(args){
        return getText(this.code, (args.discount!=-1)?"Price With Discount":"Price No Discount", [Round(args.itog), this.symbols[args.code] ])
    }
    this.ru = function(args){
        args['code']="ru";
        return this.doStuff(args);
    }

    return this;
}
```

Bear in mind I don't know what "Itog" is so I can't do it all but the basis is fairly straight forward. Potentially auto-populate object with functions and symbols from a text file or something with included tarrifs? Again, I don't understand the context but yeah.

Comment: Itog - this is the RESULT, or rather the final price. Thank you! I'll consider your option, it's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which take two parameters

```
function fullText(x,y) {
    if(x!=1){
            if (obj.Price.Discount) {
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceWithDiscount', [Round(obj.Price.Itog), obj.Currency.symbol]);
            }
            else {
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceNoDiscount', [Round(obj.Price.Itog), obj.Currency.symbol]);
            }
    }
}
```

Create another function for non ru code

```
fullTextNonRu(x,y){
       if (x) {
            if (y) {
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceWithDiscount', [Round(obj.Price.Itog), obj.Currency.symbol]);
            }
            else {
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceNoDiscount', [Round(obj.Price.Itog), obj.Currency.symbol]);
            }
        }
  }
```

Use switch case depend on obj.Language.code

```
switch(obj.Language.code){
    case "ru":
        fullText(obj.Tariff.typeCalc ,obj.Price.Discount);
        break;
    default:
        fullTextNonRu(obj.Tariff.typeCalc ,obj.Price.Discount);
        break;
 }
```